# Google drive change api

Tags: google-drive-api

Using the google drive change/list api, I can get the changes since my last "list" query. The problem is that it includes "all" changes (i.e. even if the user have viewed the file).

The question is, how do I filter and obtain only the changes to the file "content" efficiently?

Comment: The api does have an option to return since a given point.

Comment: @ZigMandel I am using that parameter. The question is how to "only" get the changes in the file content. As opposed to changes on view date, etc

Comment: Viewing a file isn't enough to constitute a change. It may well be that the Docs web app automatically makes a change when you open a document, and if that's what you're seeing, you're snookered. All I can suggest is store a local list of md5Sums and compare them with the new md5Sum.

Comment: This is an annoyance.  I don't find that the changes feed contains entries for when users just 'view' a file though, it does contain cosmetic changes though, like adjusting a column size.